# Pass either a double or a vector<double>& to a function

Tags: c++, vector, variant

I have a function which calculates the first derivative dy/dx for discrete values y(x) stroed as std::vector:

`vector<double> CalcDerivative(vector<double>&y, vector<double>&x) {...}`

Often the spacing dx is constant so it would be more efficient to pass a double to this function instead of vector<double> as argument x.

I tried to accomplish this with std::variant. The drawback with std::variant is however, that it cannot handle references so the vector x has to be copied while being passed as a variant to the function.

For now I solved the problem by defining two functions with overloaded arguments. But I wonder whether there is a more elegant solution which won't duplicate the code for the two cases (x as double or as vector<double>).

Comment: Personally, I'd say an overload is a pretty elegant (and certainly readable) solution. To avoid code duplication, extract a method for the common parts (you did not provide code so I cannot be more specific). Also, there's nothing intrinsically wrong with copying data. Don't do premature optimizations.

Comment: Either pass the 1 value also as a `vector` and check `if (x.size() == 1)` or make the `x` argument a template and then check `if constexpr` it is a `double` always use this and if not use the index of the array.

Comment: [`std::reference_wrapper`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper) or just a pointer? Or a template? Difficult to tell without a [mre]

Comment: Regardless of what solution you come up with, the function that takes a vector of one value should still work.  Don't take away the functionality for the user if they want to pass to you a vector of one value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution might be to define the "worker" function such that it is independent of the "number of passed doubles". For this purpose, `std::span` is suitable. The exemplary solution might look like:

```
std::vector<double> CalcDWorker(
  std::span<const double> y, std::span<const double> x)
{
  ... // x.size() == 1 indicates uniform spacing
}

std::vector<double> CalcDerivative(
  const std::vector<double>& y, const std::vector<double>& x)
{
  return CaclDWorker({y.begin(), y.end()}, {x.begin(), x.end()});
}

std::vector<double> CalcDerivative(
  const std::vector<double>& y, double x)
{
  return CaclDWorker({y.begin(), y.end()}, {&x, 1});
}
```

It requires C++20, but there are third-party `span` implementations available also for earlier C++ versions (such as the one provided by Boost).

Live demo: https://godbolt.org/z/n6adEKWes